# Swift 3: EKEventStore doesn't remove single events with RecurrenceRule

Tags: swift3

This is my simplified event delete function that doesn't work with recurrenceRule well. 
EventStore is created once at app load. 
Editing and saving single event with recurrenceRule works fine, but removing event with recurrenceRule deletes all events instead of one, no matter what EKSpan I pass. Also deleting future events (EKSpan.futureEvents), deletes previous events also from same recurrenceRule. Everything else looks like works fine.

What am I missing? Thank you for your time.

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()


func deleteEvent(_ storedEventID: String)
{
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
        if (granted) && (error == nil)
        {

            if let calendarEvent_toDelete = self.eventStore.event(withIdentifier: storedEventID){

                //recurring event
                if calendarEvent_toDelete.recurrenceRules?.isEmpty == false
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Repeating Event", message:
                        "This is a repeating event.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    //delete this event only
                    let thisEvent_Action = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete this event", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
                    {
                        (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                        //sometimes doesn't delete anything, sometimes deletes all reccurent events, not just current!!!
                        do{
                            try self.eventStore.remove(calendarEvent_toDelete, span: .thisEvent)
                        } catch let e as NSError{return}

                    }


                    alert.addAction(thisEvent_Action)

                    if let topViewController = UIApplication.topViewController(){
                        topViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen
                        topViewController.present(alert, animated: true)
                    }
                }
                //not recurring event
                else{
                    //works fine
                    do{
                        try self.eventStore.remove(calendarEvent_toDelete, span: EKSpan.thisEvent)
                    } catch let e as NSError{
                        return
                    }
                }
            }

    }
    })
}
```

Comment: found my issue, its not in the posted code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped

```
func deleteEvent(calendarEvent_toDelete: EKEvent){
    ...
    calendarEvent_toDelete.recurrenceRules?.removeAll() 
    try self.store.save(calendarEvent_toDelete, span: .thisEvent)

    try self.store.remove(calendarEvent_toDelete, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
    ...
}
```